SqlDelight Coroutines Flow doesnt emit data to Jetpack Glance widget
I am building a small todo list widget for fun and learning. I wanted to use SqlDelight for persisting the data and Jetpack Glance for building the android widget. This is my code:
in GlanceWidget
override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {
    val pageRepository =
        EntryPoints.get(context, PageProviderEntryPoint::class.java).pageRepository()

    val initialPages = pageRepository.getSortedPages(config!!.databaseId, null)

    provideContent {
        val pages by pageRepository.getSortedPagesFlow(config.databaseId, null)
            .collectAsState(initial = initialPages)

        GlanceTheme {
            CheckListLayout(pages)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

in PageRepository
fun getSortedPagesFlow(
    databaseId: String, filter: Filter.CompanionFilter?
) = localDatabase.getSortedPagesFlow(databaseId, filter).onEach { println("debug pages count ${it.size}") }


fun getSortedPages(
    databaseId: String, filter: Filter.CompanionFilter?
) = localDatabase.getSortedPages(databaseId, filter)

in LocalDatabase
override fun getSortedPages(
    databaseId: String,
    filter: Filter.CompanionFilter?
): List<Page> {
    return  dbQuery.selectAllPages(databaseId, ::mapToPage)
            .executeAsList()
            .filter { filter?.evaluate(it) ?: true }
            .sortedBy { Instant.parse(it.lastEditedTime) }.reversed()
}


override fun getSortedPagesFlow(
    databaseId: String,
    filter: Filter.CompanionFilter?
): Flow<List<Page>> {
    return dbQuery.selectAllPages(databaseId, ::mapToPage)
            .asFlow()
            .mapToList(Dispatchers.Main)
            .onEach { println("debug pages count localdb ${it.size}") }
            .map { pages -> pages.filter { filter?.evaluate(it) ?: true }}
            .map { pages -> pages.sortedBy {  Instant.parse(it.lastEditedTime) }.reversed()}

}

So right now this doesn't work as I would hope. When the the provideGlance func is called in response to an widget update call it loads the data and i can see the debugging logs.
But if provideGlande is already running and i emit new data to the localdatabase there are no new event and there is no recomposition of my widget.

The reason for this were in the underlying SQL statements. Apparently, sqldelight don't emit events on a query, if you return a value.
In my case, wanted to retrieve the rowId, and I was using a grouped statement (you have the same problem with RETURNING). Now I simply create a UUID beforehand and don't auto increment my id column.
createPageOld {
    INSERT INTO PageTable(remoteId, parent, archived, properties, url, publicUrl, isSynced, lastEditedTime, databaseId)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?, ?,?);
    SELECT last_insert_rowid();
}

createPageNew: INSERT INTO PageTable(localId, remoteId, parent, archived, properties, url, publicUrl, isSynced, lastEditedTime, databaseId)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, ?,?);

Here is the corresponding issue: https://github.com/sqldelight/sqldelight/issues/3743
